# Стоит ли обращать внимание на данный warning: "narrowing conversion"?

Tags: c++, char, int

Данный код выдаёт предупреждение о смене типов с **char** к **int**, вызванной методом `toupper(char)`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    char str1[20];
    char str2[20];

    strcpy(str1, "My name is ");
    strcpy(str2, "alex");

    for (int i = 0; str2[i]; i++)
    {
        str2[i] = toupper(str2[i]);
    }

    strcat(str1, str2);

    std::cout << str1 << std::endl; // OUT: My name is ALEX

    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос в том, стоит ли воспринимать подобные предупреждения, учитывая, что переход внутри функции от **char** к **int** кажется вполне естественным?

Если же всё же стоит, то вопрос в том, как в данном случае преобразовать тип наиболее правильно по современным стандартам языка?

P.S IDE - Clion

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper

Comment: Элементарное чтение [документации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) показывает как правильно вызывать эту функцию - `static_cast<char>(std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)))`

Comment: Благодарю, не доглядел

Comment: Пока можете искореняйте предупреждения. Когда проект разрастётся, вы в них утонете и их будет намного труднее убрать.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Понял, спасибо!